# Installing packages in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

When I go to browse packages in Sublime Text 2, the packages folder is full of all the plugins I wanted like Zen coding and SidebarEnhancements. 
My installed packages folder only has package control in it though. Should other installed packages be located in here?

SidebarEnhancements, for example, does not work, even though it is in the packages folder. If I right click the sidebar I just get the "close" option. I've been trying to figure this out for weeks, and I figured I would just ask here and see if anyone could tell me what I need to do after I have the package in the packages folder, if anything.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

With Package Control in Sublime Text 2, you really need to become cozy with a couple of different things to make it all work:

1. Always look up a package in the [wbond community](https://packagecontrol.io/). There you'll be able to see how many people have installed that package (the more popular, the better) as well as the documentation on the package (if any).
2. Menu Items under `Prefs > Package Control`. Here you can install, remove or see a list of all installed packages.
3. `Prefs > Package Settings`. Here you'll find the settings that can be tinkered with as well as shortcut keys that are available. Make sure to make any changes in the User Settings, rather than the Default Settings. Otherwise, your settings will be overwritten when that package is updated.
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. This will bring up a menu where you can look up a lot of the functions your installed packages can do. Just start typing and it will start filtering.

Answer (score 22):

Here is a link to a shorter and to the point description:
http://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/packages/how-to-install-and-use-package-control/

The steps are:

1. Install package control.
2. Go to http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation and grab the install code.
3. In Sublime Text 2 open the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>) and paste the code.
4. Restart Sublime Text 2.
5. Open command palette via <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac OSX) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows).
6. Start typing Package Control and choose the package you are looking for.

Comment: Nice. Although this installs the Package Control and miss the steps afterwards

Comment: where are the "grab the install code.", i cant find it anywhere in the website

Answer (score 10):

Try using [Sublime Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) to install your packages.

Also take a look at these [tips](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: Thanks, I have been using package control to install packages. Should installed packages be in the installed packages folder or just the packages folder? It would make sense for them to be in the installed packages folder but all the tutorials and guides I have found only reference the "packages" folder. I have about a dozen useful packages that I installed through package control but it seems like only a couple are working. Sidebar enhancements is definitely not working even though I installed it through package control and it is in the packages folder.  Thanks

Comment: Actually my installed packages are in the Packages Folder :)

Comment: Installed Packages only contains a file name 'Package Control.sublime-package'

Answer (score 2):

> The Installed Packages Directory You will find this directory in the
>   data directory. It contains a copy of every sublime-package installed.
>   Used to restore Packages

So, you shouldn't put any plugin to this folder. 
For getting works of SidebarEnhancements plugin try to disable and reenable this plugin with using Package Control. If it doesn't work then try to remove folder "SidebarEnhancements" from "Packages" folder and install it again via Package Control.

Comment: I ended up figuring this out. It was installed the whole time but apparently you can only use sbe within a folder. If you just go to file>open>somefile.html you can't right click on that file and get all of sbe's options. I guess I should have known this but I wasn't using sublime in that way even though its much better.

Answer (score 2):

This recently worked for me. You just need to add to your packages, so that the package manager would be aware of the packages:

1. Add the Sublime Text 2 Repository to your Synaptic Package Manager:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
   ```
2. Update

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install Sublime Text:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sublime-text
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You may try to install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) first by following simple instructions available at [Installation Guide](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) (which is like 1. Open the Console, 2. Paste the code).

Then please check [Package Docs Control Usage](https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/usage) for Basic Functionality:

> Package Control is driven by the Command Pallete. To open the pallete,
>   press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Win, Linux) or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (OS X). All Package
>   Control commands begin with Package Control:, so start by typing
>   Package.
>
> The command pallete will now show a number of commands. Most users
>   will be interested in the following:
>
> **Install Package**
>
> Show a list of all available packages that are available for install.
>   This will include all of the packages from the default channel, plus
>   any from repositories you have added.

Answer (score 0):

**Enabling a previously-installed Sublime Text package**

If you have a subdirectory under `Sublime Text 2\Packages` for a package that isn't working, you may need to enable it.

Follow these steps to enable an installed package:

1. `Preferences > Package Control > Enable Package`
2. Select the package you want to enable from the list