# HTML/CSS/jQuery Editor with Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

Is there an editor that is as good as XCode at code autocompletion, but for HTML, CSS, and javascript. This means file parsing, so that it can be used with jQuery and other libraries such as node.js, etc. I've been looking for quite a while now. Free is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)
I've been using it for a while. Best for the combination you asked for (HTML/CSS/JS)
Also supports installable packages (for libraries like [jQuery](https://github.com/SublimeText/jQuery)). Total #win. It isn't exactly [free](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), but it isn't necessary to buy it either. 
For more about packages, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124532/installing-packages-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Does it autocomplete all three including local variables? That's the real kicker. It really decreases development time. Xcode kicks butt at autocompletion.

Comment: It absolutely does :) (shows hints almost for all HTML/Souce code files automatically, if not `Ctrl+Space` brings up the suggestions)

Comment: Is there a web debugger inside of it?

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can enable the `Web Inspector` package!

Answer (score 1):

Komodo Edit.
Compare with Notepad++ and Sublime text. Can turn on/off other languages plugin, the dictionary supports JS, HTML5 n css3, can view the result on the spitted side -no other offline free tools support this feature-, also the debug/syntax checking feature is pretty accurate.